# Getting Incorrect syntax near ')' error following a tutorial

Tags: sql-server, northwind

I am running into an issue while following along with a Udemy SQL intro course. I have written a query line for line exactly as the solution given using Microsoft SQL server management studio and Northwind database.

There is an incorrect syntax error of ***Incorrect syntax near ')'.*** popping up on line 2 after the closing parenthesis of ((od.Quantity = od.UnitPrice)). I have searched (for the last 2 hours) and I'm stumped because line for line it is the same as the answer shows. If anyone can point me in the direction of what has went wrong.

```
SELECT p.ProductName, COUNT(p.ProductName) AS [Number of Units],
SUM((od.Quantity = od.UnitPrice)) AS [Total Sale Amount]
FROM [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN
Products p
[Order Details] od
ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
HAVING SUM((od.Quantity = od.UnitPrice)) >= 30000
ORDER BY [Total Sale Amount] DESC;
```

***PHOTO ADDED FOR REFERENCE***
[Screenshot of Program and Query with results after updating operand from = to * without any other changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voICQ.jpg)

Comment: Are You sure it's a = sign and not other mathematical symbol? It should be SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice).

Comment: `SUM((od.Quantity = od.UnitPrice))` (it doesn't need 2 sets of parenthesis by the way) definitely doesn't make sense. `od.Quantity = od.UnitPrice` is a [boolean expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression); how do you propose you sum the values of `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `Unknown`?

Comment: After you fix your `SUM` expression though, you'll get a different error about `p.ProductName` not being part of an aggregate function, or within the `GROUP BY`. It would probably be a good idea to link the tutorial, as you're either following it wrong (no offence intended), or the tutorial itself is.

Comment: And just like that it's solved! User error of course. On my screen the * was not distinguished from = due to video resolution. Thank you infinity @Skaparate

Comment: @Larnu thank you also! I did not end up with an extra error. it worked by changing the operator.

Comment: @kan you have used "[Order Details] od" in inner join Product p. You should remove it. It is not correct usage. the inner join should like INNER JOIN <TableName> <Alias> ON <link between <TableName Alias> and the other tables provided before>

Comment: If you are in fact using sql server you would get the error that @Larnu was mentioning because you have no group by here. Either way I am voting to close this as off topic because it is typo issue.

Comment: If that query works now, and you've only changed the boolean operator (`=`) to a mathematical operator (`+`,`-`,`*`,etc) then you're definitely ***not*** using SQL Server. The error strongly suggests you are, and the syntax suggests T-SQL, however, T-SQL does not support the use of aggregate functions in the same query as a non-aggregated expressions without the use of the `OVER` or `GROUP BY` clauses. For example `SELECT A, SUM(B) FROM (VALUES(1,1),(1,2)) V(A,B);` will fail, as `A` is not aggregated or part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Larnu I am definitely new to this realm and it's syntax so all feedback is welcome and appreciated especially seeing your level of knowledge. I've updated and included a screenshot of my query and the results into the original post so everyone may see what was returned from my query. As I am following along with a paid Udemy course I am using the instructors information and syntax. I am going to rewrite the query using the information given by you and Zeki to see the result as I am now curious to how many ways this same result can be achieved with different query structure. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were calling `[Order Details] od` twice in your code during the Join.

I think I fixed it below:

```
SELECT
    p.ProductName
,   COUNT(p.ProductName) AS [Number of Units]
,   SUM((od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice)) AS [Total Sale Amount]
FROM [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN  Products p  ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
HAVING SUM((od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice)) >= 30000
ORDER BY [Total Sale Amount] DESC;
```

Kindly advise?